# Let $X$ be any set, $F$ be any field, and $F^X=\{f\colon X\to F\}$. Why is $F^X$ finite dimensional iff $X$ is finite

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $X$ be any set, $F$ be any field, and $F^X=\{f\colon X\to F\}$ (the set of all functions from $X$ to $F$ with usual point wise addition and multiplication by scalars). Why is $F^X$ finite dimensional if and only if $X$ is finite?

Comment: This shouldn't be too hard... If $X$ is finite then $FX \cong F^{|X|}$ hence it is finite-dimensional. If $X$ is infinite then you should be able to exhibit infinitely many linearly independent functions. You may wish to look at functions that are $1$ at exactly one point and $0$ elsewhere.

Comment: Please use some mark-up. Also, please note that most mathematicians will not identify $X$ with $x$, so it's important to not use them interchangeably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $x\in X$, let $\mathbf{e}_x\colon X\to F$ be given by
$$\mathbf{e}_x(y) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
1 & \text{if }x=y,\\
0 & \text{if }x\neq y.
\end{array}\right.$$

Then $\{\mathbf{e}_x \mid x\in X\}$ is linearly independent. Given $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in X$, pairwise distinct, if
$$\alpha_1\mathbf{e}_{x_1}+\cdots \alpha_n\mathbf{e}_{x_n}=\mathbf{0},$$
then evaluating at $x_i$ gives $\alpha_i=0$.

If $X$ is infinite, this proves that $F^X$ has an infinite linearly independent subset, so $F^X$ is infinite dimensional.

If $X$ is finite, $X=\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$, and $f\in F^X$, then note that
$$f = f(x_1)\mathbf{e}_{x_1} + \cdots + f(x_n)\mathbf{e}_{x_{n}},$$
so the set spans $F^X$. Thus, $F^X$ has a basis with $n$ elements, hence is finite dimensional.

Comment: Awesome, perfect, I had a rough idea but was struggling, that's sorted it all out -thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The set of elements $1_x $, where
$$ 1_x(y) = \cases{1, & y = x  \\ 0, & otherwise} $$
will always be a basis for FX.

Comment: If $X$ is infinite, how do you get the function sending everything to $1$? But this is still the right thing to look at.

Comment: It won't be a basis if $X$ is infinite, but it will be linearly independent.